# Moving Share Buttons from a Plugin

Tags: plugins

I'm using the Share and Follow plugin on my site.  I like it for the most part, but the "interactive share buttons" - the ones that appear at the front of the post - are on the first line of my post.  This might be OK, except that it shoves the images that are at the beginning of the majority of my posts out of alignment (on both [my main page](http://www.inkandpixelclub.com) and individual posts).  I would much prefer that the buttons appear under the title, but before the first line of content in my post.  But because it's a plugin, I can't figure out how to change where the buttons appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a plugin you probably don't want to edit it directly as then it will revert every time the plugin is updated. It looks like the problem is that the style has a float:left on it.

```
<div style="float:left; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; " class="interactive_left">
```

If you remove that float:left you get exactly what you want. Unfortunately for you the style is inline instead of part of a style sheet so I think your only option might be to find that bit of code in the plugin and edit it directly. You could ask the plugin author to move it to a stylesheet to make that easier but it's really up to them.